# Global scss variables in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In my src folder, I have assets/styles folder where my global scss files are.

In my `index.scss` I import them like this

```
@import 'assets/styles/colors.scss';
@import 'assets/styles/links.scss';
@import 'assets/styles/basics.scss';
```

And then in index.js, I import compiled `index.css`

Problem: In `basics.scss` I'm using variable from `colors.scss` and getting an error `Undefined variable: \"$black\".`

And the same happens in components scss files if they use variables from that file. I really don't want to import colors in every single component. Is there a way to make these 3 files global?

To work with scss in reacting I'm using [Adding a CSS Preprocessor (Sass, Less etc.)](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/69c3d4b04c233ba9fb9d16691056bd09076177b1/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) (Since moved [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/)).

**UPD**
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use partials when importing parts into index.scss

```
@import 'assets/styles/colors';
@import 'assets/styles/links';
@import 'assets/styles/basics';
```

The filenames should be

```
_colors.scss
_links.scss
_basics.scss
```

You can read more about this in the [SASS docs](https://sass-lang.com/guide) under the Partial section.

Comment: Ok, did that. But when  I try to use $black in my App.scss file I'm still getting Undefined variable. Although now it works in basics.scss

Comment: Can you show what your tree structure is? It might be that you are not importing things correctly.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Thanks Allan. Make sure to import App.scss as well into index.scss. Placing the general style files (containing vars) at the top and component partials below it.

Here's an example. It's a project of mine where I import several vars and component styles into an app. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rscheffers82/React-List-Application/tree/master/app/styles)

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it. The problem was that I had index.scss, where I imported all scss files and which I later improted to index.js. I just removed index.scss and did all of it inside App.scss and it is all working now. Thanks!