# Import scss in react

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a react project with scss files,
I have variables file that I want to be accessible in all files.
Until now when I want to use variable in another scss file(like in component) I need to import variables file in each component that I want to use that.
I tried to use sass-resources-loader package but it also did not work.
Any idea?

[image: Error When npm start react]

Answer (score 3):

For using SCSS in React you have to install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) firstly, so you can  simply add it to your project by the command below:

```sh
npm install node-sass
# or
yarn install node-sass
```

Then you can freely change your CSS files to SCSS.

### But what is the error says actually?

In your `Layout.scss` file you are using a variable which is `$color-white` and you didn't define it in the file properly, so you should either define in like this `$color-white: #FFFFFF;` in the same file (`Layout.scss`) or define it in the other file and import the file into your current file. For instance, you can create a file and name it as `Constants.scss` like this:

```
//Constants.scss

$color-white: #FFFFFF;
```

And then import it in the `Layout.scss` just like this:

```
//Layout.scss

import "./constants.scss"; // I Assume they are in the same directory.
```

## Update

As if today the `node-sass` approach has been [deprecated](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/) and it is recommended to use `sass` instead.

So it will be like this:

```sh
npm install sass
# or
yarn add sass
```

Comment: Until now I did exactly like that, but in every component I need to import constants file. I want to import constants file once and to use that everywhere in app.

Comment: @mat Basically there is no certain way to it automatically in React apps. But there is a tricky way that you can follow (You can create partial files and add them into your entry point file). just follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807552/11908502) and tell me if you had any problem with it.

Comment: okay this works for me. what about this sass-resources-loader package? this should make sccs files available in all project files

Comment: @mat You should either use `sass-resources-loader` or `node-sass` (Don't use both of them at the same time). `node-sass` is much more popular so I just suggest to stick with that. Also if the answer works for you please make sure to mark it as an answer to allow other peeps in the community to find their answer easier if they facing the same issue. (For marking it as an answer you can simply follow [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).